# Xamarin and OpenID Connect

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, openid, .net-standard

I'm having a first go at integrating OpenID Connect authentication in a Xamarin.Forms app. I will have my own [Identity Server](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4) for users that sign up directly with my app, but also want to provide authentication through third-party providers such as Google and Facebook.

Initially I thought the best way to achieve this would be to make use of the [Identity Model](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel) package from within my Xamarin.Forms PCL. This package conforms to the .Net Standard, so in order to use it I have to change the Xamarin.Forms PCL to target .Net Standard (as described [here](https://blog.xamarin.com/building-xamarin-forms-apps-net-standard/)). Having changed the PCL to target .Net Standard, any attempt to consume the Identity Model gives the following compile error when building the Android application:

```
Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'IdentityModel, Version=2.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
```

Am I correct in thinking that this error is the reuslt of Android not supporting the Identity Model package even though it's built to .NET Standard?

If this is the case, what is the best way to consume an [Identity Server](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4) from a Xamarin.Forms application. Should I be using the Xamarin.Auth libraries? Will Xamarin.Auth work with my own Identity Server?

Comment: Did you install the package in both the PCL as well as the platform project?

Comment: I agree with Gerald's response. I've been working with IdentityModel.OidcClient for a couple of months and have been impressed.